# Deployment of hyperledger fabric on production

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i have done a PoC of hyperledger fabric for KYC now it's time for deployment.I have been through several tutorial for the deployment of hlf project.What i found is to deploy on amazon using instances.Hyperledger being a decentralised app how can it be deployed to a centralised server in this case Amazon cloud.Where should i supposed to Deploy my project in order to make it fully decentralised.

Comment: Probably best to ask this type of question on either the Fabric mailing list or on Hyperledger RocketChat

Comment: @GariSingh you can probably give some links/ references to answer it